# Correct way of MVC folder structure in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

i have problem in folder Naming in MVC thats why getting the following errors.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_View_Exception' with message    'script'browsing-
history/browsinghistory.phtml' not found in path (C:/xampp/htdocs/test_app/application 
/views\scripts/)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_app\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php:988 Stack 
trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test_app\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(884):  
Zend_View_Abstract->_script('browsing-histor...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test_app\library
\Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\ViewRenderer.php(900): 
Zend_View_Abstract->render('browsing-histor...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\test_app\library
\Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\ViewRenderer.php(921): 
Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript('browsing-histor...', NULL) 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\test_app\library\Zend\Controller\Action\Helper
\ViewRenderer.php(960): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render() #4 
C:\xampp\htdocs\test_app\library\Zend\Controller\Action\HelperBroker.php(277): 
Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch() #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\test_app
\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_app\library\Zend\View
\Abstract.php on line 988
```

this is my Controller

```
class BrowsingHistoryController extends Zend_Controller_Action{//my actions }
```

this is my action

```
public function browsinghistoryAction(){}
```

and this is my folder structure in scripts

```
scripts
 ->BrowsingHistory
   ->browsinghistory.phtml
```

i did the same thing for my controllers thats working fine dont know why this is not working ?? Any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to rename the `BrowsingHistory` folder under `/scripts` into **browsing-history** and your problem will be gone!

Basically, controllers and actions are in camelCase, but scripts aren't, you just need to transform and replace every capital letter in lower-case letter and add a dash as follow:

- **camelCase** becomes **camel-case**
- **camelCaseTest** becomes **camel-case-test**
- **BrowsingHistory** becomes **browsing-history**

Answer (score 0):

```
  Controller Name = Directory Name
  Action     Name = file.phtml
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the followig structure :

```
application/
    browsinghistory/
        controllers/
            BrowsinghistoryController.php
        models/
        views/
            scripts/
                browsinghistory/
                   browsinghistory.phtml
```

and change your controller's name to `BrowsinghistoryController` :

```
class BrowsinghistoryController extends Zend_Controller_Action{//my actions }
```